# Valor impreciso ao fazer cálculo com float

Tags: c++

Resto está dando 0.72998 e não 0.73 por que?

```
using namespace std;

int main() {

    float num=576.73;
    int x=num;
    cout<<"x "<<x<<endl;
    cout<<"num "<<num<<endl;
    num=num-x;
    cout<<"resto "<<num<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```